# Alinear a la derecha un label dentro un un td alineado a la izquierda en bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy queriendo alinear a la derecha un `label` de **bootstrap** dentro un `td` alineado a la izquierda, el objetivo sería lo siguiente:

[image: Tabla]

No lo estoy logrando, intente alinear el **span** a la derecha del **td** de la siguiente manera, pero no funciona:

```
<td  class="text-left">
    Texto de la tabla 
    <span class="label label-default text-right">0 - 1</span>
</td>
```

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Inter Milan</a></td>
    <td  class = "text-left">Texto de la tabla <span class="label label-default text-right">0 - 1</span></td>
    <td><a href="">Lazzio Roma</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Bayern Munich</a></td>
    <td class = "text-left">Texto de la tabla <span class="label label-default text-right">3 - 3</span></td>
    <td><a href="">Herta Berlin</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario de editar o crear una clase, simplemente con [las classes helper de bootstrap (Quick floats)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-floats) puedes posicionar los elementos deseado, en este caso:

- `pull-right`:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Inter Milan</a></td>
    <td  class = "text-left">Texto de la tabla <span class="label label-default pull-right">0 - 1</span></td>
    <td><a href="">Lazzio Roma</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Bayern Munich</a></td>
    <td class = "text-left">Texto de la tabla <span class="label label-default pull-right">3 - 3</span></td>
    <td><a href="">Herta Berlin</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Para la version **[4 de bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)** han cambiado el nombre de la classe `pull-*` y además lo puedes variar según el viewport:

- `float-left` | `float-right` | `float-none` - Para todos tamaños de viewport
- `float-sm-*` | `float-md-*` | `float-lg-*` | `float-xl-*` - Según el viewport

Comment: Opte por esta respuesta ya que no hace falta sobreescribir la clase label-default.

Answer (score 4):

Intenta aplicandole `float:rigth` para moverlos a la derecha:

```css
td .label-default{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Inter Milan</a></td>
    <td  class = "text-left">Texto de la tabla <span class="label label-default text-right">0 - 1</span></td>
    <td><a href="">Lazzio Roma</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Bayern Munich</a></td>
    <td class = "text-left">Texto de la tabla <span class="label label-default text-right">3 - 3</span></td>
    <td><a href="">Herta Berlin</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ¡Funcionó! Muchas gracias por la ayuda @Eirner. Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

puedes agregarle la clase .pull-right predeterminada de bootstrap con eso no agregas mas css

```css
.text-right {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Inter Milan</a></td>
    <td  class = "text-left">Texto de la tabla <span class="label pull-right text-right">0 - 1</span></td>
    <td><a href="">Lazzio Roma</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Bayern Munich</a></td>
    <td class = "text-left">Texto de la tabla <span class="label pull-right text-right">3 - 3</span></td>
    <td><a href="">Herta Berlin</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```